# Trouble with starting a process out of another process

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

If I got it right, Python doesn't accept a process to be started out of a process?! For example:

```
def function1():
    while True:
        wait_for_condition
        #then....
        process2.start()

def function2():
    does something
    process2.join()

process1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function1,))
process2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function2,))

process1.start()
```

In my test python denied to open a process out of a process.

Is there a solution with another way to solve this?

If not - Id have another way to go, but this way would include a modification of the electronics (connect one output to one input and use this to let a process wait for an event and then start. ... but I think this is not a clean way. Its more kind of an workaround. And I'd have a little risk to cause a shortcut if Input and Output is not set correctly).

---

Edit:
The Task:
Having three processes parallel. These wait for an input at one attached sensor each.
If one of these processes get an input change they should reset a counter (LED_counter) and start another process (LED_process) in not already started. After that the process waits for an input change again.

Beside that...

The LED_process starts to active one output and counting down the LED_counter. If the LED_counter reaches zero, the process terminates. If the code starts again it must be able to restart from the top of the code.

---

Edit 2:

Latest try with threading (don't be confused by some german words). If I try this code -> the different threads mixes in some strange way together. But for now I can't find a mistake. Same code with multiprocessing works fine:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import threading
import sys

LED_time = 10 #LEDs active time

#Sensor Inputs
SGT = 25
SGA = 23
SHT = 12

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(SGT, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(SGA, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(SHT, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

def Sens_check(Sensor,Name):
    print("Thread_{} aktiv".format(Name))
    while True:
        GPIO.wait_for_edge(Sensor, GPIO.FALLING)
        #LcGT.value = LED_time   
        print("{} Offen".format(Name))
        time.sleep(0.1)
        GPIO.wait_for_edge(SGT, GPIO.RISING)
        print("{} Geschlossen".format(Name))
        time.sleep(0.1)


SensGT_Thread = threading.Thread(
    target=Sens_check,
    args=(SGT,"Gartentor",))
SensGA_Thread = threading.Thread(
    target=Sens_check,
    args=(SGA,"Garage",))
SensHT_Thread = threading.Thread(
    target=Sens_check,
    args=(SHT,"Haustuere",))

try:
    SensGT_Thread.start()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    SensGA_Thread.start()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    SensHT_Thread.start()

    SensGT_Thread.join()
    SensGA_Thread.join()
    SensHT_Thread.join()

except:
    print("FAILURE")
finally:
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'll delete my general answer. I can't resolve your specific setup with `RPI.GPIO` without having the ability to test it myself.

Comment: No need to apologize. Thanks for the help. I think I found some kind of workaround. Even if this is not the neat and clean solution I was looking for. If it works it works.   
Maybe in the future someone came up with the proper solution. Until then it will run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processes can only be started within the process they were created in. In the code provided, `process2` was created in the main process, and yet tried to be started within another one (`process1`). Also, processes cannot be restarted, so they should be created each time `.start` is used.

Here's an example of starting processes within a process:

```py
import multiprocessing
import time


def function1():
    print("Starting more processes")
    sub_procs = [multiprocessing.Process(target=function2) for _ in range(5)]
    for proc in sub_procs:
        proc.start()
    for proc in sub_procs:
        proc.join()
    print("Done with more processes")


def function2():
    print("Doing work")
    time.sleep(1)  # work
    print("Done with work")


print("Starting one subprocess")
process1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=function1)
process1.start()
print("Moving on without joining")

"""Output of this:
Starting one subprocess
Moving on without joining
Starting more processes
Doing work
Doing work
Doing work
Doing work
Doing work
Done with work
Done with work
Done with work
Done with work
Done with work
Done with more processes
"""
```

Comment: Thank you! This does the trick. To take the definition of the subprocess into the process is the solution.